# Excel VBA copy worksheet to existing sheet in unopened workbook

Tags: excel, vba

VBA novice here.

I recorded the included code to copy a worksheet from the source workbook and paste it into a sheet of another open workbook.

It works but what I was attempting to do is; 
trigger macro
copy worksheet
open destination workbook
paste data
close origin workbook
end on destination workbook but different worksheet.

```
Sub Button5_Click()
'export data to template
Sheets("DataSet").Select 'sheet that I want to copy and paste (resides in macro workbook)
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Missing Data Template (concept1).xlsx").Activate 'destination workbook (no macros)
Sheets("Report").Select 'destination worksheet
Cells.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Thanks for some education!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will have to open the other workbook, paste, and then close:

```
Sub Button5_Click()

    'a variable to hold our other workbook
    Dim otherwb as Workbook

    'open other workbook assign it to variable
    Set otherwb = Application.Workbooks.Open("Missing Data Template (concept1).xlsx")

    'Copypasta
    Sheets("DataSet").Cells.Copy Destination:=otherwb.Sheets("Report").Range("A1")

    'save and Close other workbook         
    otherwb.Close(true)   

End Sub
```

You'll notice, too, that I've done away with all the `.Select` and `.Active` type code. It's really unnecessary to `.Select` stuff in VBA since Selecting is something a human does. The code just needs to know what to get and where to put it. Touching with `.select` or `.activate` is really only used sometimes at the end to set the cursor/selection at a specific point for the human that is running the code (say if you wanted to insure that once this runs, the Sheets("Dataset").Range("A1") cell was selected.

Comment: when I trigger the macro it bombs out with run time error 9 (subscript out of range) at the 'copypasta step